# помогите разобраться с CELERY

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

Вопрос такой:
 по туториалу пытаюсь создать е-маркет на django. и для отправки сообщений об удачном заказе установил Celery в комплекте с Rabbitqm. в главной директории проекта создал файл celery.py и ипортировал celery в **init**.py. В директории приложения orders создал файл tasks.py и в orders/views.py в функцию order_create также добавил выполнение асинхронной задачи.

но вот проблема, если в настройках указываю EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend', то в консоль все приходит,а почта пустая. и если указываю

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
```

то соответственно и в консоли ничего не выводится и на почту ничего не приходит. все связанные с вопросом файлы публикую ниже.

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')

app = Celery('django_project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**init**.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order


@task
def order_created(order_id):
    """
    Задача для отправки уведомления по электронной почте при успешном создании заказа.
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Order nr. {}'.format(order_id)
    message = 'Dear {},\n\nYou have successfully placed an order.\
                Your order id is {}.'.format(order.first_name,
                                             order.id)
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject,
                          message,
                          'email@gmail.com',
                          [order.email])
    return mail_sent
```

views.py

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                         product=item['product'],
                                         price=item['price'],
                                         quantity=item['quantity'])
            # очистка корзины
            cart.clear()
            # запуск асинхронной задачи
            order_created.delay(order.id)
            return render(request, 'orders/created.html',
                          {'order': order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm
    return render(request, 'orders/create.html',
                  {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

Comment: `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`

Comment: пробовал, все остается тоже самое.

Comment: возможно ли такое поведение из-за того что все запускается на localhost?